# How to write a Bash script to edit many text files using the same commands?

Tags: bash

I'm very new to `bash`. I have ten text files that I want to edit with the same line of code.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i -e 's/.\{6\}/&\n/g' -e 's/edit/edit2/g' | tr -d "\n" | sed  's/edit2/edit/g'| grep -o "here.*there" | sed -r '/^.{,100}$/d'
< files 1-10
```

I know I could use `sed -f sed.sh <file1 >file1` but that only works with sed commands and it only works one file at a time?

Do I have to run a loop?

Comment: Welcome to SO, IMHO running sed command in loop is not good, if you could let us know sample input and expected sample output in your post we could probably do it in single `awk` or `sed`. Since they are capable of reading multiple files within 1 commad itself.

Answer (score 1):

There's some great existing answers on the Unix stack exchange that help deal with your problem. Specifically, from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files?newreg=63655f028ac04f11bbf861c7bba8db9f) post, they use a loop to recursively loop through all the files in a particular directory, as follows:

```
( shopt -s globstar dotglob;
    for file in **; do
        if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -w $file ]]; then
            sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' "$file"
        fi
    done
)
```

Note the line, `shopt -s globstar dotglob;`, which allows us to use globbing patterns in the for loop. We also enclose the code in brackets, to prevent the `shopt -s globstar dotglob;` line option from becoming a global setting.

If you would like to apply this example to your file, you can just place your files in the current directory, and the code would probably look something like this:

```
( shopt -s globstar dotglob;
    for file in **; do
        if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -w $file ]]; then
            sed -i -e 's/.\{6\}/&\n/g' -e 's/edit/edit2/g' | tr -d "\n" | sed  's/edit2/edit/g' | grep -o "here.*there" | sed -r '/^.{,100}$/d' "$file"
            fi
        done
)
```

Note that we have placed a "$file" variable beside each of the `sed`s that you used in your code, this replaces the name of the file for each command.

---

There is another example given in the code that allows you to pick which files to run on, rather than all the files in a directory, which you can also re-purpose for your code, as given here:

```
( shopt -s globstar dotglob
    sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **baz*
    sed -i -- 's/foo/bar/g' **.baz
)
```

---

To answer your question of doing a loop on each line, you will need to put a loop for each line inside your for loop, like so:

```
        while read line ; do
    : sed -i -e 's/.\{6\}/&\n/g' -e 's/edit/edit2/g' | tr -d "\n" | sed  's/edit2/edit/g' | grep -o "here.*there" | sed -r '/^.{,100}$/d' "$line”
done
)
```

Although the for loop can be useful for dealing with files in recursive directories, I would recommend against also using another loop to grab lines, since it muddies your code, and it’s possible there is a better way to do it without parsing line by line.

The linked question is a fairly complete guide to many of the cases you may come across, and is also worth a read if you want to learn more.

Hope that helps!

Comment: * Can this loop be changed to read each file one line at a time? Like this?
   while read file in **; do
* Another slightly different question, that I have a problem formulating, what if I want to see certain patterns in the multiple text files echoed into a single output with an index label, file location.
output would look like
id file 1
pattern found
id file 2
pattern found
id file 3
pattern found

Comment: @meb, yes, there is a way to both loop through all the files and by each line, although I would recommend using a single sed command for the file instead. Also, it’s likely you don’t need to combine the greps and seds, because you are already ‘piping’ the outputs to the other parts with |.

Comment: If you want to have an output with a pattern that also outputs the file name, you can use echo “$file” with the for loop, so it prints out the name of the file first.

Comment: You can find some useful resources in tutorials on sed, piping, and looping in bash, all on stack exchange, especially in the Unix and Superuser stack exchange. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [for loop](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html). 
You could use the tool [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

**Example**

Create a set of test files **using a for-loop**

```
mkdir -p /tmp/so58333536
cd /tmp/so58333536
for i in 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt;do echo "The answer is 41" > $i;done
cat /tmp/so58333536/*
```

Now correct your mistake **using parallel** [1].

```
mkdir /tmp/so58333536.new
ls /tmp/so58333536/*  |parallel "sed 's/41/42/' {} > /tmp/so58333536.new/{/}"
cat /tmp/so58333536.new/*
```

`{}`:: refers to the current file

`{/}`:: refers to name of the current file (path is removed)

Reads: List all files in so58333536 and apply the following sed command to each file and write the output to so58333536.new.

---

[1] Another option is to use `sed -i` for in-place editing.

**Be very carefull with this!! Mistakes can cause serious damages!**

```
# !! Do not use -i option regularly !! 
ls /tmp/so58333536/*  |parallel "sed -i 's/41/42/'"
```